# Quick way to solve computational congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The specific problem at hand is $$34x \equiv 60 \bmod{98}$$
I reduced to get $$17x \equiv 30 \bmod{49}$$ 
and from this I have
$$17x \equiv 30 \bmod{7}$$
which is easy to solve and yields $x \equiv 3 \bmod{7}$. How can I use this fact to help me solve the more complex equation? I know the solution will be of the form $7k + 3$, but how can I utilize this fact?

Comment: You could also use the Euclidean Algorithm, to approach it directly from $17x \equiv 30 \pmod{49}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your fact directly: plug in $7k+3$ for $x$ and continue solving!

More precisely, you can take $x=7k+3$ as the *definition* of the new variable $k$, and your calculation shows that $k$ is an integer. So you can continue solving congruences to determine the complete solution for $k$, which in turn gives you the complete solution for $x$.

Comment: So $17(7k+3) \equiv 30 \bmod{49}$. But that gives $k \equiv 5 \bmod{49}$. So I have $x = 7(49k_2 + 5) +3$ now, except I don't want the +3 anymore since the 45 is the solution... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Addison: you would just expand it. However, your calculation is wrong. I'm *guessing* what your work is, and I expect that in your "reduce" step you forgot to divide everything relevant by 7.

Comment: Ahh, I see. $k \equiv 6 \bmod{7}$. It works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This may be more than you need to know, but [Hensel's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) is the big tool here.  You have $f(x)=17x-30$, which you solved modulo 7, i.e. $f(3)\equiv 0\pmod{7}$.  Because $f'(3)=17\not\equiv 0\pmod{7}$, there will be a unique solution modulo $7^2$.  That solution will be $3+t7$, where $t$ is the unique solution to $f(3)/7+f'(3)t\equiv 0\pmod{7}$.  In your case, $f(3)=21$ and $f'(3)=17$ so you want to solve $3+17t\equiv 0\pmod{7}$.  This has solution $t=6$, so $3+6\cdot 7=45$ is the unique solution mod $49$.

If you wanted to solve it modulo $7^3$, you will again get a unique solution because $17$ remains nonzero modulo $7$.  The answer will be $45+t49$, where $t$ is the unique solution to $f(45)/49+17t\equiv 0\pmod{7}$.  That is, $15+17t\equiv 0\pmod{7}$, which has solution $t=2$.  Hence $45+2\cdot 49=143$ is the unique solution mod $7^3=343$.

Comment: I'm in an upper level undergraduate course in number theory. While I'm sure it's an excellent solution, unfortunately my teacher wouldn't approve of the machinery used to arrive at it :(

Comment: You could ask; when I teach number theory to undergraduates I cover Hensel's lemma.